# Powershell Define $UNC

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm new to powershell. Where and what do I need to define $UNC as to successfully run the following powershell program?

```
$Source = "\\ahs-bind01\ftptest01\CRAR"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -recurse

$files = import-csv "C:\Users\us6205\Desktop\DatabaseNameConfigs\Test\CareMoveFileParentDestPaths.csv" 

#loop to get values and store it 

foreach ($UNC in $files)
{  
     $Path = Get-ChildItem -Path $UNC.path -recurse | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $true) -and  ( $_.FullName -match "$Source") } 
     $Dest = $path | New-Item -path $path -itemtype directory | Move-Item -Path $Source -Destination $dest -Force
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run the script? Did it not run successfully? Did you get an error? if so, what does it say?

Comment: I'm receiving a "New-Item: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null." Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Most likely because the `Get-ChildItem` statement yields an empty result. What are you trying to accomplish anyway? Please take a step back and describe the problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is that you don't have to define $UNC anywhere else. It is a temporary variable the script uses while traversing the files in the foreach-loop

Comment: I'm receiving a "New-Item: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null." Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Then that is because the Get-ChildItem query returns nothing. You need to modify that statement if you think it should return some results